# Slow compact times in gcpolicy gencon

Tags: java, performance, garbage-collection, jmeter

We are using IBM Java 1.6. We updated the default gcpolicy from optthruput to gencon in jvm parameters. We did Jmeter testing and on investigating native-stderr logs, we found compact step of garbage collection is taking a very long time, around 10-15 seconds, which affects the overall performance.

Here are the logs:

```
<gc type="global" id="103" totalid="1647" intervalms="98443.519">
    <compaction movecount="155698631" movebytes="7321564424" reason="low free space (less than 4%)" />
    <classunloading classloaders="398" classes="398" timevmquiescems="0.000" timetakenms="23.448" />
    <finalization objectsqueued="6" />
    <timesms mark="47.705" sweep="11.664" compact="11713.333" total="11797.627" />
    <nursery freebytes="2087339032" totalbytes="2295122944" percent="90" />
    <tenured freebytes="129023560" totalbytes="7650410496" percent="1" >
      <soa freebytes="129023560" totalbytes="7650410496" percent="1" />
      <loa freebytes="0" totalbytes="0" percent="0" />
    </tenured>
  </gc>
```

Any idea how we can further tune jvm settings to reduce compact time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I searched a lot but couldn't find why compaction was slow.
But I checked below answer:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/14463488/5448410

I found in some cases, compaction might not be necessary. So I added the property

> -Xnocompactgc

which disables compaction during global and system garbage collection.

I ran a jmeter test again and found gc duration improved a lot as well as the throughput.

I think compaction looks like a necessary evil. Compaction does a great job by compacting small memory chunks into larger ones, but since compaction is the heaviest overload process during gc, it can be avoided in some cases, if required.

Answer (score 0):

Before trying to tune gc, you should check:

- your heap configuration to ensure you have allocated enough heap
- you have followed scripting best-practices :

  - http://www.ubik-ingenierie.com/blog/jmeter_performance_tuning_tips/
  - http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html

it seems you’re using java6 which means you’re using an old version of JMeter since, new versions of JMeter are only compatible with Java 7/8

So start by upgrading you jmeter version.