# How to pause all threads in my process (stop the world)

Tags: c++, garbage-collection

I'm writing a garbage collector toy, and I need to pause the running program (stop the world gc) when my GC start collecting, can C++ do this?

Comment: Not vanilla C++ AFAIK but there are functions like `SuspendThread()`.

Comment: C++ no. The OS yes.  However you need to conciser the state a suspended thread may leave the process in.  Say on suspension a thread is holding a lock on the heap (in the middle of new/delete).  The process (including the GC thread) now has no heap until this thread restarts.  This applies to any other lock as well.

Comment: Do you really need to pause *all* threads or just put a lock in that blocks all other GC functions during the collect? That is, if a thread isn't doing anything GC related, does it need to be paused?

Comment: Similar issue reported here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40544480/correct-way-to-pause-resume-an-stdthread

Comment: _".. I'll read some open source runtime with gc..."_ An interpreted system is much easier as you can just stop the interpreter at an appropriate point.

Answer (score 3):

You can't simply freeze threads in C++ but you probably don't want to.  If you're doing garbage collection, surely you don't want to do that whilst some thread is right in the middle of memory allocation/de-allocation.  You probably want to have all the threads yield in some way on a regular bases, perhaps with semaphores or a global mutex, so that the gc can wait for them all to reach that state before gc'ing.  When the gc isn't active, control can be handed straight back for any yields.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by using POSIX signal library.
First, define a custom signal by using `SIGRTMIN`

Second, define a handler to handle this signal and register this handler:

```
signal(SIGRTMIN, stop_handler); // you should use sigact() instead
```

Finally, send this signal to application threads:

```
for (auto thread : threads) {
    if (thread != self) {
      pthread_kill(thread, SIGRTMIN);
    }
  }
```

P.S. how to get `threads` is varies from case to case, in my case, I add thread registration in my gc reference, if some one initialized a instance of my gc reference, I will know get the thread.

P.S. About why most GC pause the whole program, check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4491260/explanation-of-azuls-pauseless-garbage-collector)